# What, exactly, is the "Context" naming convention

Tags: asp.net, naming-conventions, httpcontext

I am trying to define when to name a class as a Context and I am having a very difficult time. Could someone please define "Context" for me and explain when to name a class "Context"?

Comment: Can you add some context to your question? What language?

Comment: Apologies - ASP.net. E.g. HTTPContext or EntityContext.

Comment: I'd add those as tags (adding right now).

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary.com *(Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2011)* defines context as:

1. the parts of a written or spoken statement that precede or follow a specific word or passage, usually influencing its meaning or effect: You have misinterpreted my remark because you took it out of context.
2. the set of circumstances or facts that surround a particular event, situation, etc.

The second definition is the applicable definition in this case.  Taking the `HTTPContext` class for example, we know that the class contains information about the web site at the current moment (including the request, the response, the session, the user, etc.)

Therefore, I would define a 'Context' in this regard as *a class that provides information about a particular application or service; or provides access to objects and methods that describe the current state of an application (or a particular facet of an application, such as a DataContext class in Linq To SQL or Entity Framework).*

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/) for "[context](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/context)" it tells us:

> the circumstances that form the
>   setting for an event, statement, or
>   idea, and in terms of which it can be
>   fully understood:

In programming a "context" class would be a class that provides your application code or code running within a framework with a set of data or objects relevant and meaningful to the task at hand.

For example, ASP.NET's `HttpContext` object provides information about the current `HttpRequest` (cookies, headers, user agent and so on). This data is meaningful only in the "context" of the current request as it may and will change for other requests.

Comment: Would it be fair to say, then, that any object that defines a state should be named Context?

Comment: @dubloons - I guess that would be fair enough. But it would be state that is relevant to the current task at hand, e.g. an HTTP request.